# Shiny app reactive function with loop does not work

Tags: r, loops, shiny

Hi i created a reactive function with a loop but it seems that it only does the first loop and does not continue after.

Here are some data in order to make the problem better visible for you guys

dont mind about the ui part, i just put it in for better understanding

**ui part**

```
  shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

  tabPanel("Revenue and Marketshare for Model 1",
                        h2("Select the discount"),
                        fluidRow(
                          column(4,
                                 selectInput("what.comfort","Choose the comfort",choices = c("0","-1")),
                                 selectInput("what.alt","Choose the Alternative to be discounted",choices = c(1,0)),

                                 actionButton("calculate1", "Calculate")))
```

**server part:**

```
 server <- function(input,output,session){
 library(datasets)
 library(mlogit)

 data("Train", package = "mlogit")

 Tr <- mlogit.data(Train, shape = "wide", choice = "choice",
                varying = 4:11, sep = "_", id.var = "id",
                opposite = c("price", "comfort", "time", "change"))
 Tr$alt[Tr$alt == "A"]               <- 0
 Tr$alt[Tr$alt == "B"]               <- 1

 f <- mlogit(choice ~ comfort,Tr)

 observeEvent( input$calculate1,{

u10 <- as.numeric(input$what.comfort)
w10 <- as.numeric(input$what.alt)
t10 <- f
train.shares <- c()
train.revenues <- c()
train.shares$SUBMcost.mod  <- discount 
train.revenues$SUBMcost.mod  <- discount 

for(discount in seq(.01,1.25,.05)){


  Tr1 <- Tr
  Tr1[Tr1$comfort == u10 & Tr1$alt == w10 , "price"] <- discount * Tr1[Tr1$comfort == u10 & Tr1$alt == w10, "price"]  
  # market shares
  dummy <- data.frame(rbind(apply(predict(t10, newdata=Tr1, outcome=F),2,mean)))
  dummy$SUBMcost.mod  <- discount 
  train.shares <- rbind(train.shares,dummy)
  # revenues
  train.price       <- Train[,c(4,8)]
  train.price$Price_A <- train.price$Price_A * discount 
  dummy          <- data.frame(rbind(apply(predict(t10, newdata=Tr1) * train.price), 2, sum))
  dummy$SUBMcost.mod <- discount
  train.revenues <- rbind(train.revenues, dummy)
  dummy <- NULL
}
})
}
```

does somebody has a solution for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Output of `revenues1` is created only within a loop. Are you sure you initialize it properly outside of the loop?

Comment: sry What do you mean? when it is not inside the loop than i does not add a new row to the output **revenues1** @RomanLuštrik

Comment: what @RomanLuštrik means is that your loop does `revenues1 <- rbind(revenues1, dummy)` but `revenues1 ` is not initialised outside the loop. It is like doing `x <- x+2` without assigning a value to `x`. This happen also for `tel1.shares`. What you need is to `tel1.shares <- df()` or similar. Also please add some data we can play with (e.g. what is `tel.m.1? ) and any errors/output you have.

Comment: @fra i put an example below, thanks in advance

Comment: You should paste the error you get, as it helps pinpoint the issue. I run your code (not at shiny) and I would check 3 things 1) You use`discount` outside the loop, but only defined it inside 2) `train.price` columns are lowercase, but you use `$Price_A` 3) `apply(predict(t10, newdata=Tr1) * train.price), 2, sum` are you sure the brackets are in the correct position?  Also, I wouldn't use `dummy` twice in the same loop as it can create confusion.